# Error running Multi Device App on Android platform using TFDLocalSQL of Delphi Community Version

Tags: android, mysql, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

I am setting up a TLocalSQL for my multi device app. I understand this component is using SQLite as backend while having my MySQL database sitting on server remotely.

On my datamodule I have setup the following:

1. TFDGUIxWaitCursor

---

1. TFDConnection — for MySQL server connection
2. TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink — MySQL driver
3. TFDQuery — MySQL table query

---

1. TFDConnection — for my LocalSQL (SQLite backend)
2. TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink — SQLite driver
3. TFDLocalSQL — my LocalSQL to handle embedded database of my app with dataset TFDQuery above
4. TFDQuery — my LocalSQL query

My data module RME:

```
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.MySQL,
  FireDAC.Phys.MySQLDef, FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB, FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs,
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, Datasnap.DBClient,
  Datasnap.Provider, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteVDataSet,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.UI;

type
  TDataModule10 = class(TDataModule)
    con1: TFDConnection;
    dvr1: TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink;
    cur1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    qry1: TFDQuery;
    loc1: TFDLocalSQL;
    dvr2: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    con2: TFDConnection;
    qry2: TFDQuery;
    dsp1: TDataSetProvider;
    cds1: TClientDataSet;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DataModule10: TDataModule10;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Now, on my main form (below RME) where my TListView is sitting connects the TFDQuery of my TFDLocalSQL.

```
unit Unit9;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt,
  Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.DBScope, FMX.ListView;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    lsv1: TListView;
    bdr1: TBindSourceDB;
    bdl1: TBindingsList;
    lcf1: TLinkListControlToField;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

uses
  Unit10;

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

I ran it in Windows 64-bit platform without any issue.

But when I tried it on my Android device platform, I am getting the following error:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] dm_u.pas(10): F2613 Unit 'FireDAC.Phys.MySQL' not found.
```

I am a bit confused because this is the purpose of TFDLocalSQL. It should handle different sources of data, be it coming from different servers, xml, etc and embed it in your application using the SQLite database.

I hope my level of understanding got it right.

Now, I am stuck on how to get around with the error. I cannot change the driver because my source data is actually from MySQL.

Can anybody enlighten me more about TFDLocalSQL. It is my first time to use it and it serves well with my purpose. Am I missing something?

Comment: FDLocalSql is mainly a way of accessing other FireDAC datasets using SQL to refer to them.  But it requires the runtime environment to have drivers to support all of the datasets the LocalSql component references.  I don't know that there is MySql support on Android or whether FD has an operable Android driver for MySQL.

Comment: RAD Studio Community Version provides 3 samples for FDLocalSQL but it is all for windows 32-bit platform. I am trying to recreate one, the xDBMS, now in multi-device app and run on Android or iOS platform and check if it works. The database though is MSAccess but I can replace with MySQL. I will get back in a while.

Comment: The samples are located here C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDLocalSQL

Comment: As promised I tried it but no avail! Now, I agree with you that FD has no operable driver for MySQL, apologies for the doubt. Now, I am wambling at possibilities to access MySQL in a mobile device platform using ClientDataset for FDLocalSQL.

Comment: After lots of research, I decided to let go of this approach. Other than MySQL, is this case, is not supported by Android and iOS, it is not ideal as well. You may want to look for other options.